# Why is {w | no prefix of w starts with b} = {w | the first character of w is a} ∪ {e}?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

> \begin{align} L &= \{ w \in \{a, b\}^* \mid \text{ no prefix of $w$
>  starts with $b$}\} \\ &= \{w \in \{a, b\}^* \mid \text{ the first
>  character of $w$ is  $a$} \} \cup \{e\} \end{align}

Why is it in union with an empty string? If an empty string from $b$ can also be a prefix.

Answer (score 3):

The unique prefix of the empty word $e$ is $e$, and it does not start with $b$. Therefore $e$ satisfies the condition "no prefix of $e$ starts with $b$" and hence $e$ belongs to $L$.

Comment: "L3= {w E {a I b} * : every prefix of w starts with b} = null set. 

L3 is equal to 0 because e is a prefix of every string. Since e does not start with b, no strings meet L3's requirement."

That is according to the book I am using. I am confused.

Comment: Take any word $w$. Then $e$ is a prefix of $w$, right? And $e$ does not start with $b$, right? Thus it is not true that *every* prefix of $w$ starts with $b$, since you just found one prefix, namely $e$, that does not start with $b$. Thus no word $w$ satisfies the condition defining $L_3$ and hence $L_3$ is the empty language.